# Could not build wheels for Pillow when installing tkdesigner

Tags: python, tkinter, pip

I tried to:

```
pip install tkdesigner
```

But i got an error

```
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

when i pip Pillow seperately, it works.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (10.0.0)
```

I tried installing zlib for windows from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm but when i tried again the same error existed

Comment: py -m pip install pyproject-toml

Comment: still the error exists

Comment: What is ur OS and Python version? I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.12.0b3.